# Using QUERY on reference cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use the QUERY function in Google Sheets like this:

```
=QUERY(A2:I62854;"select I where G='"&C2&"' AND H='"&E2&"' ")
```

This query doesn't work. I tried to manually input numbers like that:

```
=QUERY(A2:I62852;"select I where G=127 AND H=2123")
```

and it works. Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remove the single quotes`'`(they are being considered as text strings) :*

```js
=QUERY(A2:I62854;"select I where G="&C2&" AND H="&E2&" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enter your first query in a separate cell you'll see that it doesn't match with the second one:

```
="select I where G='"&C2&"' AND H='"&E2&"'"
```

You have to remove the single quotes

```
=QUERY(A2:I62854;"select I where G="&C2&" AND H="&E2&"")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that your first formula contains single quotes as well as the double quotes either side of the cell references, so you are inadvertently telling query to search for a text value rather than a number (e.g. '127' rather than 127). If you strip the single quotes out (and one of the double quotes which then becomes unnecessary as a consequence), it should work:

```
=QUERY(A2:I62854;"select I where G="&C2&" AND H="&E2)
```